# How to use table values for data colors?

Tags: powerbi

I want to visualize reports of bikes. Now bike comes in 150 different color models. I have color values (in hash) for each model. I want to visualize power bi reports with bike's actual colors (not arbitrary colors assigned by power bi)

**Model to Color**

| Model | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Model1 | #aaaaaa |
| Model2 | #bbbbbb |

**Model to Sale**

| Model | Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Model1 | 10 |
| Model2 | 20 |

How to do that in power bi? How to reference from color table instead of manually putting data color for each model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following relationship:

[image]

You can create a measure to return the appropriate color:

```
Model Color = SELECTEDVALUE ('Model to Color'[Color] )
```

Now apply background conditional formatting, using this measure:

[image]

And your model field is coloured according to the Model by Color value:

[image]